# I can't see DRF api confirm browser

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth, django-rest-framework-jwt

i want to see [image: THIS]

But my browser is [image: This]

I checked the api operation through postman.

i have no idea what is the problem..

I don't think there's a problem with the code

***This is my code
project folder urls.py***

```
url(r'^', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
url(r'^rest-auth/', include('rest_auth.urls')),
url(r'^rest-auth/registration/', include('rest_auth.registration.urls')),
url(r'^account/', include('allauth.urls')),
url(r'^accounts-rest/registration/account-confirm-email/(?P<key>.+)/$',
    confirm_email, name='account_confirm_email'),
```

***settings.py***

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        # 'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
        'rest_framework.permissions.DjangoModelPermissionsOrAnonReadOnly',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
    ],
}
REST_AUTH_SERIALIZERS = {
    'USER_DETAILS_SERIALIZER': 'accounts.serializers.UserSerializer',
}
```

Any hint would be very very very appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `rest_framework.renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer` to default renderer classes of the `REST_FRAMEWORK` settings.

```
...
'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
        'rest_framework.renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer',
  ]
...
```

Comment: No worries. Happy to help 